# Erasing data in vector via loop causing breakpoints

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I have a vector of class objects (bullets) and it works for the most part. But as soon as I try to delete the bullets it loops back and then causes a breakpoint. "basic game.exe has triggered a breakpoint." I have tried iterating backwards and forwards, but it always gets stuck.

I'm using SFML, and the objects are rectangle with positions, rotations and sizes.

```
    for (it = bullets.end(); it != bullets.begin(); it--)
    {
        it->draw(game); 
        it->move();
        if (it->bullet.getPosition().x > 800)
        {
            bullets.erase(it);
        }
    }
```

I'm a noob at coding, so if you need other infomation ill try and provide it.

Comment: erasing an element from a `std::vector` will invalidate all its iterators (in this case `it`), invoking undefined behaviour  ( because you are attempting to use `it-1` in the next loop cycle, `it->draw(game); // access invalid iterator` ).

Comment: What is valid though is bullets.erase(it--); but then you'll have to reconsider your for loop

Comment: Even first `it->draw(game);` is UB (as `it` is `end()`).

Comment: You probably want to take a look at the [erase/remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call erase() on a vector, the iterators become invalid.
Instead, consider trying this:

```
 for (auto it = bullets.begin(); it != bullets.end();)
 {
    it->draw(game); 
    it->move();
    if (it->bullet.getPosition().x > 800)
    {
      it = bullets.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
      it++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: i changed my code to this and it worked. thanks, but can you explain why this works and mine doesn't?

Comment: @Mitchell After you call erase the iterator becomes invalid. erase() returns an iterator to the element that follows the erased element, therefore validating the iterator again, which is what happens in the code above

Comment: @Kevin sure, I misread and missed that the return of `erase()` is used to reset `it`. Downvode => upvote.

Answer (score 3):

You may fix your loop with

```
for (auto& bullet : bullets) {
    bullet.draw(game);
    bullet.move();
}
bullets.erase(std::remove_if(bullets.begin(), bullets.end(),
                             [](const auto& bullet) {
                                 return bullet.getPosition().x > 800;
                             }),
              bullets.end());
```

Comment: I think your erase is slightly wrong (besides being `bullet::erase` instead of `bullets.erase`). You need to give the end iterator too.

Comment: @Kevin: Indeed, typos fixed.